# Is there a adt bundle for Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: android

So far i have looked all over the interwebs and can not find a adt bundle for Linux Ubuntu. 
Is there a link for one or is there even a way to setup it for Ubuntu if there is how.

Please let me know if i miss spelled some thing wrong or did not ex plane some thing very well.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html The Linux bundle works with Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no distribution specific ADT bundle release from Google. You have to pick the ADT bundle for Linux. That's just a zip file you need to unpack in some directory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the adt bundle for Linux straight from http://developer.android.com on Ubuntu.  The site walks you through how to set it up and get started.  Not everything needs to be done with a package manager.

Comment: i found it thank you i have it for windows at the are hiding the sdks for other platforms very sneakily.

Comment: Well, it's much easier to find if you're browsing from a Linux computer.  They use http meta information to try to point you at the right one, and that "other platforms" link in case you just want to download then copy.